# Trouble with utf-8 encoding/decoding

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8

I am reading a `.csv` which is `UTF-8` encoded.
I want to create an index and rewrite the `csv`.
The index is created as an ongoing number *and* the first letter of a word. 
Python 2.7.10, Ubuntu Server

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
counter = 0
tempDict = {}
with open(modifiedFile, "wb") as newFile:
    with open(originalFile, "r") as file:
        for row in file:
            myList = row.split(",")
            toId = str(myList[0])

            if toId not in tempDict:
                tempDict[toId] = counter
                myId = str(toId[0]) + str(counter)
                myList.append(myId)
                counter += 1
            else:
                myId = str(toId[0]) + str(tempDict[toId])
                myList.append(myId)

            # and then I write everything into the csv
            for i, j in enumerate(myList):
                if i < 6:
                    newFile.write(str(j).strip())
                    newFile.write(",")

                else: 
                    newFile.write(str(j).strip())
                    newFile.write("\n")
```

The problem is the following.
When a word starts with a fancy letter, such as

- Č
- É
- Ā
- ...

The id I create starts with a `?`, but not with the letter of the word.
The strange part is, that withing the `csv` I create, the words with the fancy letters are written correct. There are no `?` or other symbols which indicate a wrong encoding.

Why is that?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: And if you're on Windows, it might be using locale encoding.

Comment: @TimMartin 2.7.10, working on an `Ubuntu Server`

Comment: @JoshLee working on an `Ubuntu Server` and I then download the file onto a windows computer. However, the error is already visible when I check the file on the `Ubuntu Server`

Comment: Just guessing, but are you sure the file actually contains a `?`, and it's not your terminal choking or something?

Comment: @JoshLee When I open the `csv` I created (Upstream, on the server) I see that within same row my `id` contains a `?` while the word next to it (which I write in the file to) starts with the proper letter - and not a `?`. I downloaded the `csv` and opened it in sublime with `utf-8` encoding. Same here. The word from which I extract the first element for the id is written without any `?` while the id starts with a `?`. And this only happens with these "fancy" letters

Comment: Oh no! Sublime text seems to replace invalid bytes with question marks without any warning or error, which is alarming to say the least.

Comment: @JoshLee holy! That is good to know! However, I do not thinkg that this is the problem because in the same file, the same letter which should be the `?` is displayed correctly! I also get a `?` in `R-Studio`. Maybe its on the python side?!

Comment: Oh, your code certainly has Unicode errors, but you need to understand what you're looking at :)

Comment: @JoshLee could you explain what you mean by "Unicode errors" and "understand what I am looking at"? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python 2.x strings are by default non-unicode - [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) returns a non-unicode string. Use [`unicode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode) instead.

Besides, you must open the file using `utf-8` encoding through [`codecs.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) rather than the built-in [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: Hm, but why are the other words encoded correctly? Would an upgrade to python 3.x solve that problem?

Comment: @Stophface *why are the other words encoded correctly* In `toId[0]` when `toId` happens to start with a multibyte character, you are actually taking just the first byte of it whereupon it stops being a valid character. The rest of you processing simply copies the input data intact (splitting by commas doesn't introduce any problems).

Comment: @Stophface *Would an upgrade to python 3.x solve that problem* Yes

Comment: oh wow. I did not know that it only takes the first bytes. I thought python  "knows" that these bytes belong together and then takes them all.

Comment: @Stophface *I thought python "knows" that these bytes belong together* It does so for unicode strings. But as I wrote in the answer, `str` type of Python 2.x (unlike Python 3.x) is a non-unicode string.

Answer (score 3):

By all means, you should not be learning Python 2 unless there is a [specific](http://py3readiness.org/) legacy C extension that you need.

Python 3 makes major changes to the unicode/bytes handling that removes (most) implicit behavior and makes errors visible. It's still good practice to use `open('filename', encoding='utf-8')` since the default encoding is environment- and platform-dependent.

Indeed, running your program in Python 3 should fix it without any changes. But here's where your bug lies:

```
        toId = str(myList[0])
```

This is a no-op, since `myList[0]` is already a `str`.

```
            myId = str(toId[0]) + str(counter)
```

This is a bug: `toId` is a `str` (byte string) containing UTF-8 data. You never, ever want to do anything with UTF-8 data except process it one character at a time.

```
with open(originalFile, "r") as file:
```

This is a style error, since it masks the built-in function `file`.

There are two changes to make this run under Python 2.

1. Change `open(filename, mode)` to `io.open(filename, mode, encoding='utf-8')`.
2. Stop calling `str()` on strings, since that actually attempts to encode them (in ASCII!).

But you really should switch to Python 3.

There are a few pieces new to 2.6 and 2.7 that are intended to bridge the gap to 3, and one of them is the [io](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) module, which behaves in all the nice new ways: Unicode files and universal newlines.

```
~$ python2.7 -c 'import io,sys;print(list(io.open(sys.argv[1],encoding="u8")))' <(printf $'\xc3\x84\r\n\xc3\xb9\r\n')
[u'\xc4\n', u'\xf9\n']
~$ python3 -c 'import sys;print(list(open(sys.argv[1],encoding="u8")))' <(printf $'\xc3\x84\r\n\xc3\xb9\r\n')
['Ä\n', 'ù\n']
```

This can be useful to write software for both 2 and 3. Again, the encoding argument is optional but on all platforms the default encoding is environment-dependent, so it's good to be specific.

Comment: In Python 2, you should use `io.open()`, which more closely matches Py3 `open()` and gives proper universal line support

Comment: Thanks, my 2to3 is a bit rusty :)